# Module not found: Can't resolve 'redux' : "./node_modules/react-redux/es/connect/mapDispatchToProps.js"

Tags: reactjs, redux

After installing redux trying to run application but getting error like "can't find the module" in mapDispatchToProps.js which is available in nodemodule folder.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please run below command.

```js
npm install --save redux react-redux
```

It should solve your problem.